# Content type slug in route, how?

Tags: 8, routes

I have a content type "Company", each company will have a login page that show the logo of the company and a login form via Restful.

I have created a module that define a route:

```
company_md.login:
  path: '/{company_slug}/login'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\company_md\Controller\DefaultController::login'
    _title: 'Company XX Login'
```

When I go to that URL it give me Not Found 404, whats wrong in my routing?

## EDIT 1

This how the path look:

```
http://companies.local/node-13-company/login4
```

## EDIT 2

My routing file:

```
testd8.name:
  path: '/node/{node1}/login'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\testd8\Controller\DefaultController::login'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
  options:
    parameters:
      node1:
        type: entity:node
```

[image]

Comment: The system name of your entity type has to be "company_slug", just FYI since you did not mention that. Also in your controller you have to have argument such as login(EntityInterface $company_slug) so DI will work properly. But as I am looking at the route I think the issue is in the missing requirements. Add something like requirements: access: 'TRUE' which grants access to the route. Then change it to something else once(entity access or permission).

Comment: @IvanJaros Please check the edit section and see the full path.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an entity type or a content type? If you create one in the UI, it's a content Type. Then it really is a node, so what you want to use is {node}. Then upcasting will work (assuming you have NodeInterface $node in your controller).

That said, access denied is, as Ivan Jaros said, the missing access definitions. The default access definition is that that access is denied. `access: 'TRUE'` will give anyone access.

What you likely want to use is `_entity_access: node:view` then the standard node access system is invoked and the user has access if he can view that node.

Comment: I'm near to get what I need, I don't know why don't recognize the content slug ? and why I need to put something whatever before the parameter route to work if I put `/{node}/login` don't work but `/something/{node}/login` work? Please check the second edit section :)

Comment: Yeah, I think I put a restriction in the relevant function back in Drupal 6 that the first part must be a fixed thing. Good question whether it could be removed now.

Comment: Not sure about that @chx, but the answer for the question for now is simple: You can't. You can however for example use aliases if you really want the first part to be a number.

Comment: @Berdir I want to put the slug not a node ID, I have asking another question here please follow this link: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182540/how-do-i-get-a-node-id-using-slug

Comment: @berdir "Not sure about that chx, but the answer for the question for now is simple: You can't" -- I know, as I mentioned I have added that restriction myself to D6 :)