# Views contextual filters url position

Tags: views, 8

I was wondering if there was a way to change the url position of a view contextual filters. normally, they are at the end of the URL after the view-name but i would like to have them after the language.

ie: example.com/fr/*filter1*/*filter2*/*view-name*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views in D8 uses for contextual filters routes and you can't put a route parameter first in a route pattern, see [Content type slug in route, how?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182437/content-type-slug-in-route-how). What you can do is aliasing. I don't know if there is a module for this, but you can build a custom path processor to change inbound and outbound the position of the route parameters in the path so that the View route does work.